Can an isolated quantum system thermalize in the sense that the time dependent density matrix of the state approaches the micro-cannonical ensemble?
Usually people are interested in ETH, or if subsystems of the closed system thermalizes, or in a restricted set of observables or arguments of cannonical typicality or quantum chaotic systems which are non-integrable, but how realistic are these? What is the organizational way in which I can view all of these?
I understand that these are rather difficult questions, but I am starting to study this field but I do not understand why physicists are interested in weaker notions of thermalization than the strongest notion of density matrix corresponding to the state of a closed system being thermalized? This seems to be the expectation right, independent of any given set of observables?
What about situations where every subsystem of a closed system is seen to be strongly coupled with the rest? Does this closed system thermalize in any sense?
I believe such a strongly coupled quantum system cannot thermalize but must remain correlated, but this brings the question of why a closed quantum system like the expanding universe which initially was very highly strongly coupled but the spectrum one obtains from the CMB is thermalized and close to a black-body spectrum.
Are there situations where thermalization is not expected in a particular quantum system but is seen to thermalize in experiment? Or indeed in the same way, systems where its experimental thermalization behavior is not understood theoretically?
I am really sorry for asking such a tangled mess of questions, but any comments/answers are highly appreciated, thanks!

For isolated (ie unitarily evolving) systems $\rho(t)$ can't approach the microcanonical ensemble in terms of the usual norms or divergences, because the ensemble is stationary and the norms are unitary invariant. Same for classical systems. That's because those norms can see the detailed micro structure of the state. But the state ends up looking like the ensemble through any coarse lens, which is why weaker notions are needed.

Hi Joe, thanks for the answer, I seem to be confusing which norms you are talking about, is it just the trace of the time dependent density matrix with some observable?
Further, you are saying that the microcannonical ensemble is stationary i.e. time independent but  the evolving density matrix ofcourse is not, but then does this imply that any sort of equilibriation process approaching a time-independent state, is forbidden in the isolated setting?
It would be really helpful if you could kindly elaborate, if it is convenient thanks!

Sure! To discuss convergence to the state you want a notion of "how different are these two states". Two of the most common are trace distance (derived from the trace norm), or the relative entropy, both unitary invariant. See eg Wilde's book. This does imply $\rho(t)$ never gets any closer to any stationary state. So in the very strong sense you proposed the equilibration is forbidden, but not in weaker senses. If the strong sense did always work, stat mech would be much less confusing :)

Maybe it helps to clarify that this strong sense can occur in open systems eg canonical typicality. It then implies the weaker senses. But it can't occur for isolated systems. So the weaker senses can also occur without it.
